# Fancybox able to give two loading page pop ups ? both similar triggered?

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox, fancybox-2

i try to configure fancybox to set up two fancybox pop ups to start at once as a click trigger, one pop up with a video from youtube, as a iframe method, and the second one it should bring some information about the author that the website is created for.
I managed to set the popups run, but thing is only one is triggered, not both. (i want the video iframe to be 1st pop up, after closing, you can read the info about author.)
 Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="custom-stuff-blea">

        <li>
        <a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/fancybox/popup/video.html">Iframe</a>
       </li>
       <li>
       <a class="various2" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/fancybox/popup/info.html">Iframe</a>
      </li>
```

the JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".various2").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',

});
});
```

Ready document for the js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#custom-stuff-blea .various').trigger('click');
});
```

You can check a live preview of this at http://54.201.22.120/merlinitheme/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `onClosed` and create another fancybox. Check the API [here](http://fancybox.net/api)

Comment: +1 Good Ideea, 1st of all, i am usign fancybox2 and the closebtm action is no more onClosed, it goes with 'afterClose'. But all the credits go to you !

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got a fix to this, 1st you need to set a afterClose in the java for the js code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".various").fancybox({
 'afterClose': function() { 
        $("#custom-stuff-blea .various2").fancybox().trigger("click");
    }
```

After this add the settings for the second popup (various2)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".various2").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    });
});
```

Good to go now !